# Does SO have a widget for displaying all your recent questions and answers?

Tags: support, flair

What I'm looking for is something that is the SO equivalent of this Twitter widget:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines#user

The only widget I have found so far is the [user profile image flair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair)

If SO or SE does not provide these widgets, do they provide, an API or RSS feed from which it is possible to construct these?

Answer (score 1):

Stack Exchange does not provide any "widgets" other than the user profile flair.

If you want to use the [Stack Exchange API](http://api.stackexchange.com/), you can check if there's anything in there that will suit your needs.

Additionally, at the bottom of every user profile page is a link to an RSS feed for that user's activity on that particular Stack Exchange site:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: And remembering that [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com/) has many goodies built with the API.